# Pyinstaller choose Winpython

Tags: python

I try to use winpython (3.6.2), which lies in the folder "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.2.amd64", to make a .exe from my python program. I have also Python 2.7 installed in "C:\Python27". When I now try to build the .exe with "pyinstaller --onefile --window Test.py" it always picks python version 2.7, but the program is made for python 3.6. Any suggestions what I could do here?